# tray component for Delphi

Tags: delphi, system-tray, trayicon, tray

Please advice some modern tray component for Delphi. The more functionality it has is better. It should support Delphi 2010. I just need to place an icon to tray and handle clicking on it and show popup when mouse cursor is over it.

Comment: Delphi 2010 distribution has `TTrayIcon` component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about [TTrayIcon](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33415). It's been in Delphi since Delphi2006.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a very old delphi version (older than 2006) then try the free TJvTrayIcon in the JEDI VCL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the Raize suite has a tray icon component. The suite isn't free, but we've used it for years and are find it invaluable.

http://www.raize.com/devtools/RzComps/Default.asp