# Cannot Find the TTrayIcon Control in Delphi enterprise version 7

Tags: delphi

i am using Delphi enterprise version 7 and want to drop a TTrayIcon Control to a form. My problem is that i cannot find where the control is in Control collection. I have also read that TTrayIcon belongs to the unit ExtCtrls. I added the unit to my application but when i get that TTrayIcon is undeclared. Could you please help me?

Comment: D2006 was the version this component was introduced, [`The New TTrayIcon Component in BDS 2006`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33415).

Comment: See also [`tray component for Delphi`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8500504/576719) for alternatives.

Comment: I've used [CoolTrayIcon](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=245) in D5 and D7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TTrayIcon component was added after Delphi 7. Your version does not include it. You'll need to find another component, or call Shell_NotifyIcon directly.

Comment: I still call Shell_NotifyIcon in modern Delphi.

Comment: Sure, that is possible too, but I found having a component that takes care of the nitty-gritty details a little easier. ;-)